# Not able to edit texts in WordPress Widget

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress website from recently I am unable to edit any text in the widgets. Once I drag and drop a text widget it loads and just gets saved without allowing me to add any texts. Even the existing widgets are also disabled to edit.

Please help to sort out this issue as I need to add more additional information to the website.

I have attached an image of the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your developer console in browser. I believe that there is some Javascript error in back end.

Try to deactivate all plugins & switch to a default theme. Then activate plugins one by one.